# mocking the request module with sinon

Tags: node.js, mocking, sinon

I want to mock the following piece of code using sinon,

```
  request(options, function(error, response) {
    if (error) {
      reject(error);
    } else {
      resolve(response);
    }
  });
```

can you help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it as a get request,

```
let request = require('request') // request module.
let options = "some url" // mock data for url
requestStub = sinon.stub(request, 'get').callsArgsWith(0, options);// first argument of request call is options.
requestStub.yields(error, response)//It returns error and response. These will be mock data
sinon.assert.calledOnce(requestStub)//Test to check whether stub is called or not.
requestStub.restore(); // need to restore stub every time after use.
```

So depending upon what error and response you pass, it will return output accordingly.